# how to sort the chunk of list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of rates, which contain almost 35040 values in it. I have divided my list into 365 blocks of 96 elements in it. Now I want to get the first 4 minimum values from each block and to achieve that first I am sorting blocks in increasing order and printing or inserting the first 4 elements from the list into a new list.
my approach:

```
import pandas as pd

inputFile = "inputFile.xlsx"
fileName = inputFile
inputSheetDF = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name='Sheet1')

iexRate = inputSheetDF['IEX Price']
#iexRate = [2.3, 2.4, 3, 4, 3.2, 4.1, 5.......]

testList = []

n = 96

x = [iexRate[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexRate), n)]
x.sort()
```

but this `x.sort()` giving me an error.

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

So basically I want an output in that `testList` which contains the first 4 minimum elements in each 96 block.

Comment: please read the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
iexRate = pd.Series(range(1,100))

n = 15

x = [iexRate[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(iexRate), n)]

testList = [sorted(block)[:4] for block in x]
```

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [16, 17, 18, 19], [31, 32, 33, 34], [46, 47, 48, 49], [61, 62, 63, 64], [76, 77, 78, 79], [91, 92, 93, 94]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proposed solution, which has the advantage of being vectorized. I'm using a much smaller dataset - 3 chunks of 4 each, sampling the top (button) 2 from each chunk - but the idea for a larger dataset is of course the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"rate": np.random.randint(1, 100, 12), "chunk":  [1]*4 + [2]*4 + [3]*4 })
print(df)

==> 

    rate  chunk
0     81      1
1     51      1
2     50      1
3     83      1
4     33      2
5     88      2
6     97      2
7      2      2
8     22      3
9     23      3
10     4      3
11    83      3

df.sort_values("rate", inplace=True)
df.groupby("chunk").head(2).sort_values("chunk")

==>

    rate  chunk
2     50      1
1     51      1
7      2      2
4     33      2
10     4      3
8     22      3
```

To get a flat list of all the rates, just do :

```
flat_list = list(res.rate)
==> [50, 51, 2, 33, 4, 22]
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer and yes of course logic for the larger dataset will be the same but I need to find a way to do that with the list because in my code I want to use this value for further calculations also. So it would be really helpful if you could provide the basic solution where program just the divide the list into chunks and then sort the each chunk.

Comment: do you want that as a flat list (one long list of rates) or as a list of lists (a list of 96 lists, each with 4 elements?)

Comment: In the iexList there are total 35040 value. So I want to divide that list into 365 total blocks of 96 elements and then get the first 4 minimum elements from the block. Now yes I want one flat list which contains the result of first 4 minimum elements from each block.